# Batch - check If program is running , if not , run it

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mc_com.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "mc_com.exe" >NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Program is running
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mc_com.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "mc_com.exe" >NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"NEQ"0" (D:\Software\Programs\MediaCompanion\mc_com.exe -e -m -v)
```

How do I get this to run mc_com.exe if it is not already running but if it is running to just end the script?

Working Solution

```
tasklist|find /i "mc_com.exe" >NUL
if errorlevel 1  (start "" D:\Software\Programs\MediaCompanion\mc_com.exe -e -m -v)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use

```
tasklist|find /i "mc_com.exe" >NUL
if errorlevel 1  (start "" D:\Software\Programs\MediaCompanion\mc_com.exe -e -m -v)
goto :eof
```

That is, start mc_com if it's not already running, if that's what you want (and assuming your `mc_com` parameters are correct)

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, you should just need to put an exit, start, and goto like this:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mc_com.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "mc_com.exe" >NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Program is running
goto procede
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mc_com.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "mc_com.exe" >NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"NEQ"0" (D:\Software\Programs\MediaCompanion\mc_com.exe -e -m -v)
start mc_com.exe

:procede
exit
```

If this is not what you are looking for please let me know.
Best of luck.

Comment: It doesn't seem to run the program with the flags it just goes to exit no matter what. I need to run mc_com.exe from that directory. I don't really need it to tell me anything just. If mc_com.exe is running exit if not run it.

Comment: Really I don't think I need NEQ just the if mc_com.exe is not running then run it otherwise exit. Could I shorten it up more?